# Редирект мобильного трафика с учетом user-agent

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, mobile, redirect

Приветствую!
Подскажите, как можно сделать редирект мобильного трафика с учетом ОС мобильных?
Например для iOS (ipad и iphone) отправлять на одну страницу, android на другую, а например symbian и остальные на третью. И соответственно windows nt отправлять на основную версию сайта.
Лучше сделать определение user-agent и редирект через htaccess или java?

Answer (score 4):

Попробуй через htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:iphone|ipad)
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://site/ios/ [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:android)
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://site/android/ [R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (?i:symbian)
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ http://site/symbian/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать через [.htaccess, php или javascript](http://webmaster.alexanderklimov.ru/view_articles.php?id=34). Я бы отдал предпочтение php.

Comment: Как задолбавшийся на планшете от любителей поредиректить на бесполезно-куцые версии страниц, не могу не высказаться.

JS-вариант учитывает возможность, выставив cookie, посмотреть на мобильном устройстве нормальную версию сайта (часть про `document.cookie.indexOf("iphone_redirect=false") == -1`). PHP-вариант, в том виде как он там — нет. Делая редирект обязательно помните об этом.