# Адаптация веб-сайта

Tags: html, сервер

Написаны две версии одного веб-сайта.
 Условно "первая" версия залита на сервер и доступна по адресу "первый_сайт.домен",
 дизайн рассчитан на устройства с экранами больших размеров т.е. компьютеры.
 Внешний вид и функционал "второй" версии адаптирован под мобильные телефоны и планшеты.
 Как объяснить серверу когда и какую версию выдавать на запрос пользователя?
 Какое имя или расширение должен иметь "второй" сайт, нечто вроде "м.второй_сайт.домен"?
Спасибо.

Comment: возможно это заинтересуется http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/138217/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-user-agent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mobiledetect.net/
По поводу поддомена для мобильной версии, это как вам угодно, значения не имеет.